ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.indices.multi_modal'
I have been trying to get all the necessary packages installed on my visual studio code for my project, after I run this command of Python app.py on my Visual Studio Terminal, I get this error of ModuleNotFoundError:
No module named 'llama_index.indices.multi_modal',
I tried running several commands like
pip install llama_index.indices.multi_modal

And also like pip install llama_index.all but I still get that error after running the line of Python app.py.

Did you try to follow the installation instructions at https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/getting_started/installation/ ?

It looks like the issue might be related to changes in the module structure of the llama_index library. The module llama_index.indices.multi_modal has likely been moved or renamed in a newer version.
Please check the documentation for the latest changes, but to address your specific issue:
Previously, you might have imported these modules like this:
from llama_index.indices.multi_modal.base import MultiModalVectorStoreIndex 
from llama_index.storage.storage_context import StorageContext


In the latest versions, you should update your imports to:
from llama_index.core.indices import MultiModalVectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.core.storage import StorageContext

Make sure to install the updated version of llama_index using:
pip install llama-index --upgrade

This should resolve the ModuleNotFoundError you're encountering.
